# How to replicate SQL Check Constraint (with Length Function) in Django Models

Tags: django-models

I created a table with SQL in Postgresql.  Now, I am trying to replicate the same via Django models.

**The SQL:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS EntryMode
(
    ModeID SMALLSERIAL PRIMARY KEY
  , Name TEXT NOT NULL
        UNIQUE
  , Acronym TEXT NOT NULL
        UNIQUE
  ,
    CONSTRAINT name_char_length CHECK (length(Name) < 51)
  ,
    CONSTRAINT Acronym_char_length CHECK (length(Acronym) < 9)
);
```

**The attempt using Django Model:**

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.functions import Length

models.CharField.register_lookup(Length)
 
class EntryMode(models.Model):
    modeid = models.SmallAutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.TextField(unique=True)
    acronym = models.TextField(unique=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = "entrymode"
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(
                name="name_char_length",
                check=models.Q(name__length__lt=51),
            ),
            models.CheckConstraint(
                name="acronym_char_length",
                check=models.Q(acronym__length__lt=9),
            ),
        ]
```

**The outcome:**
I get an error message and a traceback:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unsupported lookup 'length' for TextField or join on the field not permitted.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try:  name = models.CharField(max_length-255, unique=True) and acronym = models.CharField(max_length-255, unique=True)

Comment: @KrystianKazimierczak, Charfield gives me **VarChar(n)** type in Postgres. As much as **Varchar(n)** types offer in-built contraints, I wanted something that I could change later in the future without dropping or redefining tables.  `CHECK` Constraints over `TextFields` provide the flexibility for that kind of change.

Answer (score 2):

Silly me.   I spotted the issue

**The error was on Line 4:**

```
models.CharField.register_lookup(Length)
```

Line 4 registers the Length function for CharField; but the Constraints in EntryMode model are checking TextField attributes instead.  Length function was not registered for TextField therefore the constraint could not check character lengths that field (migration fails). Correcting line 4 fixed the issue.

**Fix:**

```
models.TextField.register_lookup(Length)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).